# Refreshing div content with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reload the content of a div without actually refreshing the page, the problem is that I just need to reload the div not to load another different page. I've been trying to use the code below but it doesn't load the div I need and it gets stuck in a loop after first refresh (refreshing every 1 sec). Or is there any way to restart a jQuery animation every 5 sec?

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {  
    $('#wrapper').fadeOut("slow").load('../index.php#wrapper').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.  `setInterval` sets up a repeating timeout, which doesn't seem to be what you want

```
var refreshId = setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('#wrapper').fadeOut("slow").load('../index.php#wrapper').fadeIn("slow");
}, 5000);
```

Also, I think you want to pass a callback to load, to be sure you're fading it back in only after the ajax request is complete.

```
var refreshId = setTimeout(function(){ 
     $('#wrapper').fadeOut("slow").load('../index.php#wrapper', 
                      function() { $("#wrapper").fadeIn("slow") });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: either i am doing something wrong or just dosn't wanna work on me

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood Well are you getting any errors?  Are you seeing the ajax request go over the wire in FireBug / Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: i had a conflict with a preloader tnks for help yes u were right the setInterval function caused the infernal loop :)